# Zeppelin z. function documentation

Tags: apache-zeppelin

I might misunderstood some concept but I'm trying to figure out where is the documentation for Zeppelin command such as `z.input`, `z.get` or `z.angularBind`.
I've found documentation here:
[Zeppelin Docs](https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/latest/manual/dynamicform.html)
But it's not technical, what I want is to have the description of the method such as the one found in `javadoc` or `pydoc`. But I can't manage to find that for Zeppelin specific method and function.
How can I know the return value and parameters of all those functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the docs are published as such in that format. But that doesn't stop you from generating them yourself

```
git clone https://github.com/apache/zeppelin
cd zeppelin
git checkout v0.7.3
cd zeppelin-interpreter
mvn javadoc:javadoc
```

That will give some error but just ignore them. Then apidocs will be available at `zeppelin/zeppelin-interpreter/target/site/apidocs/index.html`

[image: API Docs]

**Edit:**
If you encounter the error:

```
[...]JavaScript found in documentation comment.
[ERROR] Use --allow-script-in-comments to allow use of JavaScript.
```

You can edit the script `zeppelin/zeppelin-interpreter/target/site/apidocs/javadoc.sh` and edit it to add the option: `--allow-script-in-comments` so the line finishes with :

```
javadoc --allow-script-in-comments @options @packages
```

Comment: I'm going to do this and let you know how it ends. Thank you.

Comment: So far impossible to build it. I always end up with zeppelin-interpreter: An error has occurred in JavaDocs report generation: Unable to find javadoc command: The environment variable JAVA_HOME is not correctly set.

Comment: Do you have Java installed and JAVA_HOME environment variable defined?  Which OS are you using?

Comment: Maven 3.5.5 and plugin javadoc 3.0.0 are installed on ubuntu 18.04, JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/. Now JAVA_HOME is set properly but still there's so many error folder generated is empty. `java:49: error: package javax.annotation is not visible
import javax.annotation.Generated`

Comment: I have tested this with `Java 1.8.0_172` and `Apache Maven 3.5.3 (3383c37e1f9e9b3bc3df5050c29c8aff9f295297; 2018-02-25T01:19:05+05:30)`. Please check which versions have you used?

Comment: Java is 1.11 on my computer I'll test with JDK 8

Comment: Thank you ! It's amazing too bad they do not publish it.